# On back press - Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Im writing an android application which has 2 Activities. when I want to start the second one from the first, i just do as follow:

```
Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(k);
```

but when I want to move back to that activity, I don't want to make a new activity because I think that's not correct! but for `OnBackPress()` I have just called `finish();` 
but I faced that error. It gets to last activity and also the application apparently works correctly but that exception throws!
Here is the AboutActivity:

```
package com.example.ruby;
import com.example.ruby.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AboutActivity extends Activity {
TextView titleTxt;
TextView mainTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    titleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TitleTxt);
    mainTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AboutTxt);

    mainTxt.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Btabassom.ttf");

    titleTxt.setTypeface(face);
    mainTxt.setTypeface(face);
    }
}
```

I have checked many forums and I have also see

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

but I have nothing to put here. I don't know how to handle this error!
any idea?

Comment: did you register your receiver ?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan What is the register!?? I haven't any register in my code. Or better to say I don't know what that is!?

Comment: if you don't register so why you want `unregisterReceiver`?

Comment: if you don't registered any receiver just call `finish()`. this method close activity and you don't need onPause() and onStop() either

Comment: I have just did that. I just called the onBackPress() method and then I have called this.finish(); 
but that exception throws anyway

Comment: did you remove unregisterReceiver? can you post more code, because this exception said you register one receiver in your code

Comment: Post the code of your ToolsActivity.

Comment: Dears, I have uploaded the aboutActivity which is exactly the same of the ToolsActivity and has that exception too

Comment: @Melquiades I have added that part which has the exception

Comment: You mentioned about calling finish() in onBackPressed(), and I don't see it in AboutActivity, is it there? Also, please comment the line mainTxt.setMovementMethod(...) and see test again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return from the 2nd to the 1st activity via buttonclick for example just call finish() in it's onClick() method. Only the current activity will be terminated and thus the first activity will be shown again.

You don't have to modify the onBackPressed() method if you just want to show the first activity again. Don't call finish() in onBackPressed()! The first activity is stored in the backstack and only will be recreated if the OS needed to free some memory.
Also see here:
 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html